# Using Javascript to obtain the name of a web element

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var name = unescape(decodeURIComponent(
    unescape(unescape(unescape(url)))
    .replace(/\s/g, '+')
    .replace(/^.*\/|\?.*$|\#.*$|\&.*$/g,'') || 
    url.replace(/.*\/\/|www./g,'')
    .replace(/[^\w]+/g,'_')
    .replace(/^_*|_*$/g,''))
).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

The above code is to obtain the name of a web element, but I don't understand how it works, so can someone explain the details of it for me?

Comment: What do you mean by "web element?"

Comment: for MДΓΓ БДLL, web elements mean the elements on a web page, like images.

Answer (score 2):

Learn what [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are.

.

If you do not know what [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are, then that's the first thing you need to learn, because that's essentially all this code is doing is using regular expressions. For example, the code `.replace(/\s/g, '+')` will replace all whitespace characters in the string with a `+` symbol. Presumably that's because Google will always do that for you when you use Google search.

`.replace(/^.*\/|\?.*$|\#.*$|\&.*$/g,'')` will get remove everything before the first `/` in the uri, and will also remove all queries. For example, `google.com/some/page.html?var=value` would become `some/page.html`

[`decodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) is a javascript function which will take a string encoded with [Percent-Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and turn it into a normal string.

The `||` operator in javascript will return the left operand if the left operand is true, else it will return the value of the right operand. In this case, it looks like the author is using this operator as a conditional. He firsts tries to unencode the url three times before eliminating parts of the string with regex. If doing that produces an empty string, then the `||` operator will return the value of the right operator and will then (and only then) jump straight to regex replacement without unencoding first. Why? I don't know why the author would do this, but that's what's happening.

There's a few other details happening, but that's the gist. Basically, you should learn regex if you really want to know what is happening.

Comment: Hi, Thr4wn, thanks for your reply, but I have 2 more questions: 1. why did the author try to unencode the url 3 times, then further unencode using additional `decodeURIComponent` and `unescape`? 2. why did the author first use `.replace(/\s/g, '+')` to replace all whitespace characters in the string with a `+` symbol, then use `.replace(/\+/g, ' ')` to replace the `+` symbol with whitespace? Thank you very much!

Comment: Chaohuang, I am glad to help. But to help further, I will need examples of what the input will be, where you saw this code, and what you mean by web elements. I am familiar with js and regex, but I want to know the domain of application better. Thanks.

Comment: These codes are from a chrome extension called "cloud save", which allows you to directly save a web element (like an image) from a web page to you cloud storage (like google docs, dropbox, etc.) without saving it to your own computer then uploading it to your could storage. You can find the codes in my question at here: https://github.com/antimatter15/cloudsave/blob/master/cloudsave.js (between line 111-118)

Comment: Given the full context, I can now see that this is clearly a quick hack he made to get something done :). So because the code is not clean and/or neat, you would have to ask him to get more understanding.